# Access denied print server object on asp.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, printers

[image]

I guess i am just a little confused as to why this is happening. When i log into the IIS server and launch the app locally using localhost it works fine. If i try to reach the site remotely i get this. To query the printers i am using

```
 drpPrinter.Items.Clear();
        PrintServer server = new PrintServer(@"\\"+drpServer.SelectedItem.Value);
        PrintQueueCollection queueCollection = server.GetPrintQueues();

        foreach (PrintQueue pq in queueCollection)
        {
            drpPrinter.Items.Add(pq.Name);
        }
```

Comment: does IIS or your site has enough right? I.E. partial/full trust and windows security settings

Comment: Not quite sure what you mean.